# Sliding door banner with minimum width

Tags: css, html

I have inherited a site where the single image banner has a logo on the left and a bigger logo on the right.

I have chopped the banner into three, bannerLeft, bannerRight and a slice called bannerMiddle.

I want to position the three so the middle banner will stretch and contract according to the browser width, however I will need to have a minimum width so when the middle banner has 0 width, the other two does not wrap.

the left banner image is 100px wide, the right is 420px wide and the middle is 10px wide, but needs to stretch

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bannerDiv">
      <div id="bannerLeft"><img src="images/bannerLeft.png"></div>
      <div id="bannerMiddle"><img src="images/bannerMiddle.png"></div>
      <div id="bannerRight"><img src="images/bannerRight.png"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here the css which unfortunately does not work

```
#bannerRight { float:left }
#bannerRight { float:right }
#bannerMiddle { width:100% }
```

I am sure it is a FAQ, however also an issue of knowing a little hurting my progress since I have not been able to find the search arguments to find the best way of doing this. All sliding doors I have found are buttons in an unordered list

**Questions:**

1. How do I get the three images to look like one image (like they now actually do at SO)
2. how do I stop the banner from resizing to less than the combined width of left and right

Here are the 3 images:

[image: bannerLeft][image: bannerMiddle][image: bannerRight]

Actually the middle one will be ugly if repeat-x so here is another one

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

This does not quite work - if I make the middle banner 100% it overflows the right banner
Please update using my images since the right one has rounded corner!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        #bannerDiv {min-height:98px; min-width:520px; position:relative;display:block;width:100%;padding:1px;}
        #bannerLeft {  display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0px;width:100px; height:98px}
        #bannerRight { display:block;position:absolute;top:0;right:-10px;width:420px; height:98px}
        #bannerMiddle { min-height:98px; display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:100px; background-image:url(images/bannerMiddle.png)}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bannerDiv">
      <div id="bannerLeft"><img src="images/bannerLeft.png" style="height:98px"></div>
      <div id="bannerMiddle"></div>
      <div id="bannerRight"><img src="images/bannerRight.png"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

This works for now

```
<div id="bannerDiv"><img 
  id="bannerLeft" src="images/bannerLeft.png" /><img 
  id="bannerMiddle" src="images/bannerMiddle.png" /><img 
  id="bannerRight" src="images/bannerRight.png" /></div>

function resizeIt() {
  $("#bannerDiv").width("100%");
  var leftWidth = $("#bannerLeft").width(), 
      rightWidth = $("#bannerRight").width(),
      newWidth=$("#bannerDiv").width()-(leftWidth+rightWidth);
  $("#bannerMiddle").width(newWidth).height(98);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  resizeIt();
  $(window).on("resize",resizeIt);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div { min-height:20px;}
        #bannerDiv {position:relative;display:block;width:100%;padding:1px;overflow:hidden;}
        #bannerLeft {  background-color:black;display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0px;width:20px;}
        #bannerRight {  background-color:green;display:block;position:absolute;top:0;right:-1px;width:20px;}
        #bannerMiddle { background-color:purple;display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:20px;width:100%;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bannerDiv">
      <div id="bannerLeft"><img src="images/bannerLeft.png"></div>
      <div id="bannerMiddle"></div>
      <div id="bannerRight"><img src="images/bannerRight.png"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My response was a standalone sample aimed at solves the positioning problems, so you should be able to adjust it (widths/heights, offsets) to suit your needs.

Comment: I do not see my middle image. Will that be a background image of the middle div?

Comment: Yes you need to add it - the sample simply gives you the positioned elements that you can build on.